# How to run flutter application natively on android and ios separately?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am working on flutter application, and i want that application to load and run natively on android studio without flutter sdk separately so that i can put some dependencies of native kotlin or java there and run natively from there.

I copied the android folder from flutter project and create a new native android application from it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gct08.png)

Comment: have you tried installing the `Flutter` plugin in Android Studio?

Comment: yes, i already have flutter plugin installed in android studio. i Also attach pic of error when i only run android version in android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced the same issue , after researching the internet I got to know that there are one way to include our flutter project to android as module and than you can use Flutter.createView to load your flutter widget. It is simple as that, you can also follow this blog for step by step instrucation

https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-flutter-to-existing-android-ios-app-ae8c4fb1582e

Comment: Thankyou for sharing, this article is showing to convert an existing native application to flutter but if we want to reverse the process how can we do that?like if we have flutter project and we want to include 3rd party libraries that are not available on flutter, then how can we move to native version to add that dependencies.

Comment: you can create cutome plugin with android and ios

Comment: http://flutterdevs.com/blog/creating-a-flutter-plugin-for-android-and-ios-image-gallery/#targetText=These%20are%20the%20steps%20to,Select%20the%20Flutter%20plugin%20option.&targetText=Above%20code%20will%20communicate%20with,in%20Android%20and%20iOS%20files.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open `android` folder in Android Studio and `ios` folder in Xcode. Flutter tools will generate needed modules for Android Studio project and CocoaPods for iOS project. You can also run and debug your app using native debuggers (Java/C/Objective-C/Swift) from these IDEs.

Then you can easily add dependencies by changing `build.gradle` of your android application. I think it's a bit more complicated with ios.

Comment: Yes i did that but when i open the project it gives the sync error in gradle. I also attached the pic of error above in question

Comment: @Umair you mentioned that you copied a folder and created a new project from it. You don't have to do that, you just leave it in your flutter project's folder and then open it in AS

Comment: Also make sure your flutter project compiles in any way, for example, using `flutter run` command. Check that your _pubspec.yaml_ is good. Reset Android Studio caches using File -> Invalidate Caches, run `flutter clean` command, remove _flutter/bin/cache_ folder.

Comment: If i run like that it will be a flutter project. I want to make it android project only thats why copy the android folder from flutter project and open it in android studio.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening exactly `android` folder in AS and not a project's folder itself? AS should detect flutter project only when you open a whole project.

Comment: Yes i only copy the android folder from flutter project and paste it in test2 folder and import project of test 2 in android. It still showing error message of :app:compileFlutterBuildDebugArm and gradle sync issues error ERROR: Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1. And note that i didnot include pubspec.yaml file in it